# Unable to concat strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, operators, concatenation

I have a method to log with the following definition:

```
void log(std::string s) {
    std::string tag = "main";
    std::cout << tag << " :" << s << std::endl;
}
```

I'm trying to call this method like this:

```
log("direction" << std::to_string(direction) << ", count: " << std::to_string(count));
```

`direction` and `count` are integers.

I'm getting this following error with `<<` underlined in red:

> no operator << matches these operands.
>   operand types are const char [10] << std::string

I have `#include<string>` in my header to make sure my strings are working as they should.

I tried `std::string("direction")` and still the issue was same.

Beginner in C++. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::string("direction") + std::to_string(direction)` ...  What you're trying to concatinate is a char array and a string; not 2 strings

Comment: This was not required: `"direction" + std::to_string(direction)` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute the `<<` with the `+` operator as you are manipulating the string, not the stream:

```
log("direction" + std::to_string(direction) + ", count: " + std::to_string(count));
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<` isn't used for arbitrary string concatenation - it is called an *"output stream operator"*, and it is only used in the context of `std::ostream`.

When you say...

```
std::cout << tag << " :" << s << std::endl;
```

...you're actually writing code roughly equivalent to:

```
std::cout.operator<<(tag).operator<<(" :").operator<<(s).operator<<(std::endl);
```

As you can see `operator<<` knows how to work with `std::cout` and `std::string`, but not between strings.

---

In order to concatenate `std::string` instances, you can simply use `operator+`:

```
log("direction" + std::to_string(direction) + ", count: " + std::to_string(count));
```

Please note that this concatenation technique is not the most efficient: you might want to look into `std::stringstream` or simply use `std::string::reserve` to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.

Comment: Okay. But I just changed `<<` to `+` and I don't see that error anymore. Conversion still necessary?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed: yeah sorry, you don't actually need to convert `"direction"` to an `std::string` explicitly as `operator+` is defined for `(const char*, const std::string&)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to use the `operator<<` notation you need an object that understands it.

Here's such an object (I make no claims that this is a good idea):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void log(std::string s) {
    std::string tag = "main";
    std::cout << tag << " :" << s << std::endl;
}

struct string_accumulator
{
    std::ostringstream ss;

    template<class T>
    friend string_accumulator& operator<<(string_accumulator& sa, T const& value)
    {
        sa.ss << value;
        return sa;
    }

    template<class T>
    friend string_accumulator& operator<<(string_accumulator&& sa, T const& value)
    {
        return operator<<(sa, value);
    }

    operator std::string () { return ss.str(); }
};

inline auto collect() -> string_accumulator
{
    return string_accumulator();
}

int main()
{
    int direction = 1;
    int count = 1;
    log(collect() << "direction" << std::to_string(direction) << ", count: " << std::to_string(count));
}
```

Comment: `std::ostringstream` is such an object and is standard

Comment: you could also write a `std::string operator << (std::string, std::string)` if you don't want to use such an object ... I'm not suggesting it, but you can

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's why I used it :)

Comment: @UKMonkey apart from the whole "surprising behaviour in the global namespace" argument, you'd have difficulty when it came to io manipulators. This is why I've proxied the ostringstream. It also now by default understands everything in <iomanip>.

Comment: @RichardHodges ohh, I'm not at all suggesting that someone implement that operator, but it's just another way of having that syntax  :)  Even you in your answer said 'I make no claims this is a good idea' so I put another suggestion under the same heading

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of your function is `void log(std::string s);`. It awaits for an `std::string`. So you need to pass a string to it, not a stream!

So, change this:

```
log("direction" << std::to_string(direction) << ", count: " << std::to_string(count));
```

to this:

```
log("direction" + std::to_string(direction) + ", count: " + std::to_string(count));
```

where I only changed the `<<` operator to `+` operator. It will now concatenate everything inside the parentheses to a single `std::string`.

---

Your attempt implies that you wanted to pass `std::ostream` as the parameter. Maybe you want to read [C++ Passing ostream as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507924/c-passing-ostream-as-parameter?rq=1). However, if I were you, I would just overload `<<`.

Comment: Oh. That's definitely helpful. So, if I use `std::ostream` will it work? Let me test that.

Answer (score -2):

why don't you use:
 // just include this`using namespace std;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: a) That's terrible advice and b) it doesn't even answer the question.